# Python multiprocessing pool doesn't take an iterable as an argument

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I've read many posts here about multiprocessing.pool, but I still don't understand where the problem in my code is.

I want to parallelize a function using multiprocessing pool in python. The function takes one argument and returns two values. I want this one argument to be an integer and want to iterate over this integer. I've tried the examples I've seen here, but it doesn't work for me (apparently I do something wrong, but what?) 
My code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def function(num):
    res1 = num ** 2  # calculate someting
    res2 = num + num  # calculate someting
    return res1, res2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 10

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    # next line works, but with [something,something,...] as an argument
    result = pool.map(function, [1, 100, 10000])
    # next line doesn't work and I have no idea why!
    result2 = pool.map(function, range(num))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(result2)
```

I get `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` when I calculate `result2`.
Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Can you specify if you're running in python 2.7 or python 3.3+? It might be relevant. I did run your code in Python 3.6 and had no error at all. I'll guess you're using python 2.7.

Comment: What is the *numpy* import doing. Please ensure that you have an actual [mcve]! Also check the indentation. I am pretty sure this is caused by something else now...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'd say it is MCVE just with an extra irrelevant import. More importatnt was python version

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel `range` in Python 2.7 would create a *list*, there would not be a single float. The program has no single `float` in it, there is no operation that would produce a float.

Comment: @kristina: if you *copy-paste* this program into a file and then run it, what exception will you get?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel hint: test in Python 2.7 before you start speculating. The output is *identical* on both versions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok, fair enough. But at least for me, testing in Python 3, I don't get any error.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel 
I've tried running it on both Python 2.7 and Python3.5. In Python3.5, I get an error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". In Python2.7, I get an error "TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: @Kristina **the program in the question** is not the same as **the program you're running**. Please ensure that you provide a proper [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm really sorry but there was indeed a mistake in the function, not in the way of parallelizing it. Sorry for a not correct question! However, writing here did help me, because I found the error in the end.
So, this way of parallelizing actually works! Thank you for your help.